# How to capture error thrown from shell script & display it in groovy?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, groovy

I am basically trying to establish a SSH connection to a Linux machine and execute shell commands in my groovy script as shown below :

```
#!groovy

def serverName51 = "********"
def folderName = "tmp"
node('linux') {
    def output = sh returnStdout: true, script:"ssh -q karthik@${serverName51} 'cd /tmp; mkdir ${folderName};'"
}
```

The above code is returning an error message as shown below :

```
ERROR: script returned exit code 255
```

I understand there is some error thrown in shell script execution.
 How to capture & display this error in groovy?

Answer (score 0):

So you are showing us a dsl to execute shell scripts here?

In the internals of your DSL, you must be creating a Process object. I use the java.lang.ProcessBuilder directly.

Explictly:

```
Process process=new ProcessBuilder().directory(workingDir).command(["sh", "ls -l"]).start()
```

`Process` has several methods that will allow you to get the output of your shell command, as well as the exit code:

```
/**
 * Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the
 * subprocess represented by this {@code Process} object has
 * terminated, or the specified waiting time elapses.
 *
 * <p>If the subprocess has already terminated then this method returns
 * immediately with the value {@code true}.  If the process has not
 * terminated and the timeout value is less than, or equal to, zero, then
 * this method returns immediately with the value {@code false}.
 *
 * <p>The default implementation of this methods polls the {@code exitValue}
 * to check if the process has terminated. Concrete implementations of this
 * class are strongly encouraged to override this method with a more
 * efficient implementation.
 *
 * @param timeout the maximum time to wait
 * @param unit the time unit of the {@code timeout} argument
 * @return {@code true} if the subprocess has exited and {@code false} if
 *         the waiting time elapsed before the subprocess has exited.
 * @throws InterruptedException if the current thread is interrupted
 *         while waiting.
 * @throws NullPointerException if unit is null
 * @since 1.8
 */
public boolean waitFor(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)

/**
 * Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the
 * process represented by this {@code Process} object has
 * terminated.  This method returns immediately if the subprocess
 * has already terminated.  If the subprocess has not yet
 * terminated, the calling thread will be blocked until the
 * subprocess exits.
 *
 * @return the exit value of the subprocess represented by this
 *         {@code Process} object.  By convention, the value
 *         {@code 0} indicates normal termination.
 * @throws InterruptedException if the current thread is
 *         {@linkplain Thread#interrupt() interrupted} by another
 *         thread while it is waiting, then the wait is ended and
 *         an {@link InterruptedException} is thrown.
 */
public abstract int waitFor() throws InterruptedException;

/**
 * Returns the exit value for the subprocess.
 *
 * @return the exit value of the subprocess represented by this
 *         {@code Process} object.  By convention, the value
 *         {@code 0} indicates normal termination.
 * @throws IllegalThreadStateException if the subprocess represented
 *         by this {@code Process} object has not yet terminated
 */
public abstract int exitValue();
```

Comment: Thanks @loteq for the response. I am not sure about what you mean by DSL here ? I have basically created a Jenkins job using Groovy language. I am trying to execute a shell script here. I am very keen to know what you meant by DSL and is Process object part of Groovy or Jenkins ?

Comment: Ah sorry I missed your response. Now I understand, you are scripting jenkins. A DSL means a Domain Specific Language. Jenkins provides methods like node() that constitute a language that you can use. I thought, from lack of context, that you were the one implementing a custom DSL in groovy, not just using an existing DSL. Here it is more a Jenkins question than a groovy question I'm afraid.